# Is it possible to set up Exchange so that all outbound emails to a specific domain must go through TLS?

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, tls

And that, if that domain doesn't have TLS turned on, email-sending fails?  I've been looking at setting up SMTP send connectors, but there doesn't seem to be an option to *enforce* TLS?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you're using Exchange 2007 or 2010 just create a send connector and specify the domain in question as a remote domain.

Then use powershell to enable or disable TLS.  Be sure to configure a certificate using [Get-ExchangeCertificate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124950.aspx) and [New-ExchangeCertificate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998327.aspx).  Take note that by default the expiration is in one year.

Next, edit your send connector to use TLS with [TLSSendDomainSecureList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124151.aspx) ...

Here are step-by-step instructions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123543.aspx

Comment: Strangely, Microsoft provides no way to *manage* this list by adding or removing one domain at a time.  If one anticipates multiple "mutual TLS" relationships with clients, vendors, etc., it becomes highly advisable to document and maintain this list separately.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recall the exact location of the setting in exchange 2007, but in exchange 2003 there is a dialog for "Outbound Security" under connector settings where you can uncheck all options (anonymous, windows) except TLS, in effect enforcing TLS.